# Cannot read property 'number' of undefined ReacJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, response

I'm using ReactJS as frontend for my appliaction. I get values from API but when I try to get them I get error "Cannot read property number of undefined". Here is my code:

```
class ViewStationComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            station: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        StationService.getStationById(this.state.id).then(res => {
            this.setState({ station: res.data });
            console.log(res.data);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.state.station.name}</div>
                <h1>{this.state.station.trains.number}}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the response, and value I try to get is number and numberOfCarriages.
[image]

Comment: trains is an array , you cannot acces the number property unless you map through it or select the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{this.state.station?.name}</div>
            <h1>{this.state.station?.trains[0]?.number}}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I get another error while trying to get access to this.state.station.name. It shows that this values is undefined. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: `console.log(this.state.station)` to see what you have there.

Comment: I get the same values as on the screenshot, but when I try to show what is in `console.log(this.state.station.name) ` i shows undefined

Comment: try change to `this.state.station[0].name`

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked but I have another issue. I have something like this `this.state = {station: { id: this.props.match.params.id,city: '', name: '',trains: [{number: '', numberOfCarriages: ''  }
                ]
            }
        }`  I don't know how to get this value from this. Because it shows undefined.

Comment: Can you please post another question in StackOverFlow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637202/how-to-get-value-from-this-state-property-of-undefined. I posted question. Would you mind taking look at it?

Comment: Just answer there :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `trains` property is an Array you can do this:

```js
<h1>{this.state.station.trains[0].number}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use map you can keep in mind that there could be more than 1 train.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{this.state.station.name}</div>
            {this.state.station.trains.map(train => <h1 key={train.id}>train.number<h1>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```