# How to get value from this.state. Property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I'm trying to pass value from one component to another. First one looks like this:

```
class ListStation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            stations: []
        }

        this.editStation = this.editStation.bind(this);
    }


    editStation(id) {
        this.props.history.push(`/add-station/${id}`);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        StationService.getStations().then((res) => {
            this.setState({ stations: res.data });
        })
    }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                        <tbody>
                            {this.state.stations.map(
                                station =>
                                    <tr key={station.id}>
                                        <td>{station.city}</td>
                                        <td>{station.name}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button onClick={() => this.editStation(station.id)} className="btn btn-info">Modify</button>
                          ...                  
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ListStation;
```

And another looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StationService from '../services/StationService';

class CreateStationComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            station: {
                id: this.props.match.params.id,
                city: '',
                name: '',
                trains: [
                    {
                        number: '',
                        numberOfCarriages: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

        this.changeCityHandles = this.changeCityHandles.bind(this);
        this.changeNameHandles = this.changeNameHandles.bind(this);
        this.saveStation = this.saveStation.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        if (this.state.station[0].id === '_add') {
            return;
        } else {
            StationService.getStationById(this.state.id).then((res) => {
                let station = res.data;
                this.setState({ name: station[0].name, city: station[0].city })
            });
        }
        console.log(this.state.station.city + 'dfddddd');
    }
```

But when I try to pass value from one component to another I get error: Property of undefined. The response I get from API looks like this:
[image]

I'm trying to edit values based on the id taken from the first component but it seems to fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (this.state.station[0].id === '_add') {
        return;
    }
```

Have a look at this if statement from your codebase I think you should remove [0] after this.state.station ... this is because  station is an object  not an Array

Comment: Yes, that's solving one problem, but the value is still undefined

Comment: @OxOx You mean in the `console.log` with `dfddddd`? That's expected because you're logging it before `getStationById` finishes, and anyways `this.setState` is asynchronous: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30782948/996081

Comment: @cbr No, I mean when passing values from one component to another. my http address is `/undefined`, and in that place should be value

Comment: @OxOx Please edit your question to include your `<Route>` and `StationService`.

Comment: @OxOx Also please consider accepting one of these answers and asking a new question, since these questions answer your original question and the new issue is separate from the `property of undefined` error.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `if (this.state.station.id === '_add') {`

Comment: Ok, but I get the error in the line `if (this.state.station[0].id === '_add')`. Should I change it?

Comment: yea change it to `this.state.station[0].trains[0].id`

Comment: @OrAssayag `station` is an object in the state, not an array.

Comment: @cbr Thanks my bad. Updated my answer.

Comment: Updated it again

Comment: Thank you, that helped solving one problem but I still have issue while passing id from one component to another, because its value is undefined. Do you know how can I solve it?